# Rsyslogd with TCP remote input doesn't write local operating system logs

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog

I configured a rsyslog daemon to accept remote logs via TCP from a Cisco device on Ubuntu 22.04.

Unfortunately, it then doesn't write the local OS logs anymore to files like `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/syslog` and I'm not able to figure out why this is happening.

Here is my configuration file for the remote input. The other Ubuntu default configuration files like `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` have not been touched in any way.

```
> cat /etc/rsyslog.d/100-cisco.conf

# This file is managed by Puppet. DO NOT EDIT.

# make gtls driver the default and set certificate files
global(
  DefaultNetstreamDriver="gtls"
  DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem"
  DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/usr/lib/rsyslog/tls_cert_letsencrypt.pem"
  DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/usr/lib/rsyslog/tls_key_letsencrypt.pem"
)

# provides TCP syslog reception
module(
  load="imtcp"
  StreamDriver.Name="gtls"
  StreamDriver.Mode="1"
  StreamDriver.Authmode="anon"
)

input(
  type="imtcp"
  port="1470"
  ruleset="incomingCiscoLogs"
)

template(
  name="QNAPFormat"
  type="string"
  string="<%PRI%>1 %TIMESTAMP:::date-year%-%TIMESTAMP:::date-month%-%TIMESTAMP:::date-day%T%TIMESTAMP:::date-hour%:%TIMESTAMP:::date-minute%:%TIMESTAMP:::date-second%%TIMESTAMP:::date-tzoffsdirection%%TIMESTAMP:::date-tzoffshour%:%TIMESTAMP:::date-tzoffsmin% %FROMHOST-IP% %APP-NAME% %PROCID% %MSGID% %STRUCTURED-DATA% %APP-NAME%:%msg%\n"
)

$outchannel outgoingCiscoLogs,/srv/rsyslog/vpngate/cisco,104857600,/usr/lib/rsyslog/cisco_rotate

ruleset(
  name="incomingCiscoLogs"
){
  $FileCreateMode 0666
  $ActionFileDefaultTemplate QNAPFormat
  *.* :omfile:$outgoingCiscoLogs
  stop
}
```

So, the remote collecting part is working as expected, but like already said, the local logs are not processed anymore. Instead, my `/var/log/syslog` only contains a very small part of messages from the Cisco device like the following one. Only messages with "message repeated X times" appear in `/var/log/syslog`. Every other message from the Cisco device is stored in `/srv/rsyslog/vpngate/cisco` appropriately.

```
<189>1 2023-09-15T12:41:00+02:00 IP.of.Cisco.Device %CiscoAppID - - - %CiscoAppID : message repeated 2 times: [ IP = some.ip.address, Received encrypted packet with no matching SA, dropping]
```

Can you guys figure out what's the logical problem here with my configuration? I'd like to have my local OS logs available and don't have these useless "message repeated X times" messages in `/var/log/syslog` :-(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Repeated message reduction can be turned off by using `$RepeatedMsgReduction off`. Note that this is **not** recommended by the rsyslog team. Regarding the missing logs, you might want to turn off the cisco logging for a bit and check if the log volume stays the same/gets bigger.